# Angular ngOnDestroy didn't fire

Tags: javascript, angular

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pag4ue)

[Demo fixed accordingly to accepted answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w5bm8f)

Consider a component, let's call it `<simple-dialog>`, with this template:

```
<button type="button" (click)="visible = !visible">TOGGLE</button>
<div *ngIf="visible">
  <ng-content select="[main]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

I omit the component TypeScript definition cause it's basically the same as the one generated by ng-cli.

Then I use it like this:

```
  <simple-dialog>
    <div main>
      <app-form></app-form>
    </div>
  </simple-dialog>
```

When i first click the button the child component is rendered; if I click the button again the child component is removed from the DOM.
The problem is that, at this point, `app-form`'s `ngOnDestroy` is not called.

I'm new to angular, so I am not sure whether my expectation is wrong.

Comment: With the given details, it's difficult to figure out the issue. I would recommend you create demo on stackblitz which will help people  understand the problem and recommend proper solutions.

Comment: You mention `onNgDestroy`, but the proper name is `ngOnDestroy`. Have you named the function correctly and ensured your component `implements OnDestroy`?

Comment: @Zircon yes, the name in the app is fine - i fixed the typo in the question - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called conditional content projection.

In your case, by using `ng-content`, the components are instantiated by the outer component, unconditionally - the inner component just decides not to display it.

If you want conditional instantiation, you should pass a template instead:

```html
<simple-dialog>
  <ng-template>
    <div main>
      <app-form></app-form>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</simple-dialog>
```

and use an `@ContentChild` annotated property to access
the template from the content within the `SimpleDialogComponent`:

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef, { static: false })
content!: TemplateRef<unknown>;
```

which can then be rendered in the template as

```html
<div *ngIf="visible">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container>
</div>
```

You can also read about this here:
https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#conditional-content-projection

Comment: Thank you, it works - I've updated the demo, just in case ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w5bm8f